# Где взять коды всех ошибок (mysql_errno)

Tags: исключения, php, mysql

Давно хотелось написать свой полноценный класс для обработки исключений при работе с mysql. Собственно вопрос - где можно найти (и можно ли вообще) все коды всех возможных ошибок?

P.S.: гугл не помог.

Comment: Есть еще вариант + перевод на русский, но временами корявый [коды ошибок mysql](http://allerrorcodes.ru/mysql/)

Comment: Постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего в [документации на MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-handling.html)

Comment: Если еще точнее то вот <a href="http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html">все коды</a>, спасибо, не так спрашивал у гугла :)<br>
Уже в предвкушении этого кодища ^^